# Adding a FillExtrusionLayer to a Mapbox Map in Android using Mapbox SDK v10.12.2

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mapbox, mapbox-android

I am attempting to create a 3D Map in Android and having issues utilizing the correct style.addStyle(fillExtrusionLayer);. I have looked at the documentation to no avail. Any help would be appreciated.

Documentation: https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/fill-extrusion/

The error I receive is:

> Cannot resolve method 'addStyle' in 'Style'

Map.java:

```
 package edu.test.it.finalproject;
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.os.Bundle;  
    import com.mapbox.geojson.Point;
    import com.mapbox.maps.CameraOptions;
    import com.mapbox.maps.LayerPosition;
    import com.mapbox.maps.MapView;
    import com.mapbox.maps.MapboxMap;
    import com.mapbox.maps.Style;
    import com.mapbox.maps.extension.style.expressions.generated.Expression;
    import com.mapbox.maps.extension.style.layers.generated.FillExtrusionLayer;
    import com.mapbox.maps.extension.style.layers.properties.generated.Visibility;
    import com.mapbox.maps.extension.style.layers.Layer;
    //import com.mapbox.maps.testapp.databinding.ActivityFillExtrusionBinding;
     
     
    public class Map extends AppCompatActivity {
     
        private MapView mapView;
        private MapboxMap mapboxMap;
     
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_building_3d);
     
            mapView = findViewById(R.id.mapView);
            mapView.getMapboxMap().loadStyleUri(Style.MAPBOX_STREETS, style -> {
                mapboxMap = mapView.getMapboxMap();
                add3DBuildings(style);
     
                // Set initial camera position
                CameraOptions cameraOptions = new CameraOptions.Builder()
                        .center(Point.fromLngLat(-77.860001, 40.793394))
                        .zoom(15.0)
                        .build();
                mapboxMap.setCamera(cameraOptions);
            });
        }
     
        private void add3DBuildings(Style style) {
            FillExtrusionLayer fillExtrusionLayer = new FillExtrusionLayer("3d- 
   buildings", "composite");
     
            fillExtrusionLayer.sourceLayer("building");
            fillExtrusionLayer.filter(Expression.eq(Expression.get("extrude"), 
    Expression.literal("true")));
            fillExtrusionLayer.minZoom(15.0);
            fillExtrusionLayer.visibility(Visibility.VISIBLE);
            fillExtrusionLayer.fillExtrusionColor(Color.LTGRAY);
            fillExtrusionLayer.fillExtrusionHeight(Expression.get("height"));
            fillExtrusionLayer.fillExtrusionBase(Expression.get("min_height"));
            fillExtrusionLayer.fillExtrusionOpacity(0.6f);
            style.addStyle(fillExtrusionLayer);
     
        }
     
     
        @Override
        protected void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            mapView.onStart();
        }
     
        @Override
        protected void onStop() {
            super.onStop();
            mapView.onStop();
        }
     
        @Override
        public void onLowMemory() {
            super.onLowMemory();
            mapView.onLowMemory();
        }
     
        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            mapView.onDestroy();
        }
    }





activity_building_3D:
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Map">
    <!-- Other UI elements -->
 
    <com.mapbox.maps.MapView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:mapbox="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        mapbox:mapbox_cameraTargetLat="40.793072"
        mapbox:mapbox_cameraTargetLng="-77.865516"
        mapbox:mapbox_cameraZoom="9.0"
        mapbox:mapbox_resourcesAccessToken="//TOKEN GOES HERE" />
 
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `fillExtrusionLayer.bindTo(style)`. Furthermore the calls `mapView.onStart()`, `onStop()`, and so forth are not useful now because [version 10 of the Mapbox SDK now manages the `mapView` lifecycle](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/guides/migrate-to-v10/#simplified-lifecycle-management).